# MVC Acces data in view without using a @Foreach (var item in model)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

I am trying to only create one "create new" where it queries the type of the product with it. But i dont know how to access without the @foreach.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Entity", "CreateEntityType", new { EntityTypeEnum = item.EntityTypeEnum})
}
</p>
```

Comment: Not at all clear! How your model looks like? What you are trying to do?

Comment: you want to create only 1 actionlink?

Comment: Yea thats just it Ehsan. And sorry for not being clear. Trying to find a way to better explain it.

Answer (score 1):

If your Model is an array and you simply wish to access the first index `[0]` for `EntityTypeEnum` (or any index) you can do the following.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New Entity", "CreateEntityType", new { EntityTypeEnum = Model[0].item.EntityTypeEnum})
```